# Using Context in Behat - The right approach

Tags: tdd, bdd, behat

What is the right approach for using `FooContext` classes in behat?

What it is by the [docs](http://behat.org/en/latest/guides.html):

> A simple mnemonic for context classes is: “testing features in a context”. (...), the way you will test those features pretty much depends on the context you test them in.

In the docs `FeatureContext` seems for me only to be a dummy context file so that you can fast create a behat test.

> The context class should be called FeatureContext. It’s a simple convention inside the Behat infrastructure. FeatureContext is the name of the context class for the default suite.

Its not saying me directly that it has to be a context file per feature.

The only real other examples in the docs are contexts like `ApiContext` or `WebContext`.

```
default:
    suites:
        web_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/web ]
            contexts: [ WebContext ]
        api_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/api ]
            contexts: [ ApiContext ]
```

What i also found was a [CommandFeature](https://gist.github.com/tPl0ch/6706427) and another [CommandLineProcessContext](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/behat/suites).

So if i have many features to test, a context file would blow up very fast.

Then i see a more likely a context file per feature example by [Marco Pivetta](https://github.com/Ocramius) using an [Aggregate as Context](https://github.com/ShittySoft/php-fwdays-2017-cqrs-es-workshop/pull/6/files).

Is it a good idea to have a single context file per feature `foo.feature`? Or are context files thought to be environmental contexts like in the docs `ApiContext` or `WebContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I prefer to divide context and features as follows:

- One folder for each domain subject
- One feature / context file for each action you can perform onto this subjects

That way you'll end up with a single suite using more than one context but with all context divided with a single responsibility.

Quick example

```
Features
|--- User
|----- login.feature
|----- change_password.feature
|----- impersonate.feature
|----- ban.feature
|----- ...
|--- ...
|--- Order
|----- checkout.feature
|----- cancel.feature
...
Context
|--- User
|---- LoginContext
|---- ChangePasswordContext
|---- ImpersonateContext
|---- BanContext
|---- ...
|--- Order
|---- CheckoutContext
|---- CancelContext
```

Each suite is composed with many context (for example, every time you need to login to check a behavior, you'll include `LoginContext` in your suite).

```
default:
  suites:
    suite_name:
      paths:
        - '%paths.base%/Path/To/Feature/File'
      contexts:
        - Path\To\Context\LoginContext
        - Path\To\A\SecondContext
        - ...
```

This approach has many advantages in terms of maintainability, intuitiveness and so on.

If you would like to have a more generic panoramic on this subject, you can [check slides from my talk at Symfony day 2017 in Milan](https://www.slideshare.net/SamueleLilli/behat-from-zero-to-hero-a-practical-guide-to-symfony-integration-and-usage-81089016)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about `ApiContext`, i have an API with 20 endpoints (growing). So would you suggest to create a context per endpoint rather then a single `ApiContext` file for all endpoints?

Comment: @FabianPicone I would strongly suggest to do so. Maybe you can divide from UI to Model to API context (as a macro-division where all explained division advice are still valid) and each API context divided by subject and actions (maybe in this case actions are not suitable and you can stay with a single API context per subject). When and if you need more than one API subject, you can compose them into your suite.